# Query particular row + remove X columns + and sum the rest in one formula?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a CSV file that I'm pulling from a database. It's in an awkward layout so I need to reorganise it and display the result in a separate sheet.

Here is a dummy example of the data structure I get.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTfjr-rd0vMIeb3qgBaq9SC8felJ1Pb4Vk_fMNXQKQg/edit?usp=sharing

It looks like that. The database grows every day by date and sometimes countries so I need to account to that in my formula.
[image]

I need to pull data per each country and display it by date.
I don't need data from Column A, C and D. And when there are multiple states I need to sum them up in one column.

It should look like this and keep growing downwards. I'm gonna use this table for a graph chart
[image]

What I've tried so far

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_to_a_separate_sheet_where_I_importing_a_row_csv_file", "CSV-source-sheet!A1:500"), "SELECT * WHERE Col2='Germany'"))
```

This works, kinda. But pulls in unnecessary columns and I can't figure out how to sum countries with multiple states. When I add `select sum(*)` it gives me a big and long error. I assume it might be because of unnecessary columns that the formula cant sum up and I don't know how to omit them. I'm stuck

I tried offset and skipping no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: whats the "another lable" and "Second lable" ??

Comment: These are the unnecessary columns that I don't need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Sheet2!B:B, Sheet2!E:BE}, 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "sum(Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&COUNTA(Sheet2!1:1)-5))&")")&" 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label Col1'Date'", 1)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmFxo2mHB3CKtkg4XBQ5CMf5b8lgaeIeV6z5v3LrZ0Q/copy)

Comment: One problem tho, Any idea why doesn't it pick up the last two columns from the dataset? I'm missing 2 last days in my results.

Comment: if you want I can give you access to my working document.

Comment: I would need to check it but try changing -5 to -3

Comment: Yay, it worked. Thank you. I actually tried that but went for -1 just to see what it does and it broke the formula, and I left it alone.

Comment: I'm running out of 5M cells limitation with this dataset. Any tips on how to handle that?

Comment: in few months this limit will be increased to 10M cells but in meantime, you could check out Google BigQuery which was created for this purpose

Comment: Big Query looks cool. Seems I know what I am going be busy with during the quarantine :D

Comment: I wonder could I wrap this formula with importrange function? I could save cells by that

Comment: for some reason all data that we transposed and textjoned is not readable by charts. Whenever I choose any country column chart says invalid type. And it won't read the date as well. Could you have a look, please?

Comment: man, you are a legend! Thank you!. Why wasn't it working in the first place? It thought I'm gonna pull all my hairs.

Comment: numbers were not numeric but plain text. now we multiplied them by 1 which converted them into numeric numbers